# Find the local maximum of a function that takes two input variables, each with a different interval

Tags: r, optimization, minimize

How would you find local maxima for the function below, with the two inputs having different intervals?

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  y/50*(100*x)^0.9 + (50-y)/y*(80*(10-x))^0.8
}
# interval for y = (0, 50)
# interval for x = (0, 10)
```

I looked into using the optim function, but I couldn't figure out how to set "par," intervals, and other arguments for the two input variables.

Comment: `f(0, 0)` equals `Inf`

Comment: With a function that doesn't have an infinite range, you could set parameters of `optim` like `method = "L-BFGS-B",
    lower = c(0, 0),
    upper = c(10, 50)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you very much for the comment!

Comment: @alistaire Thank you for your comment! Setting the lower and upper bounds was especially helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optim` expects a function with a `vector` argument (+ optional parameters), i.e. to make the function given in the question work with `optim` one has to slightly alter the function or use some kind of wrapper function, like so:

```
# Function of two scalar inputs
f_xy <- function(x, y) {
  y / 50 * (100 * x)^0.9 + (50 - y) / y * (80 * (10 - x))^0.8
}

# Wrapper or helper function with vector argument
f <- function(x) {
  y <- x[2]
  x <- x[1]

  f_xy(x, y)
}

# Default optim with starting value c(x = 5, y = 20)

optim(c(5, 20), fn = f)
```

Note: By default `optim` performs minimization.

To maximise: Set `control = list(fnscale = -1)` (Thanks to @alistaire for pointing that out in the comments.)

```
optim(c(5, 20), fn = f, control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

However, for the function given in the question the `optim` output shows that the algorithm has not converged (`$convergence != 0`) (Thanks to @alistaire for pointing that out in the comments.):

```
optim(c(5, 20), fn = f, control = list(fnscale = -1))
#> $par
#> [1] 1.591824e+00 3.861200e-34
#> 
#> $value
#> [1] 2.368542e+37
#> 
#> $counts
#> function gradient 
#>      501       NA 
#> 
#> $convergence
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $message
#> NULL
```

In the case given `$convergence` of `1` means that the maximum number of iterations was reached. One may tackle this problem by increasing the maximum number of iteration by e.g. setting `control = list(..., maxit = 500))`. However, this will not solve the problem as `optim` still fails to converge.

Comment: If you look in `?optim`, a convergence code of 1 means it hit the maximum iterations, so this may need further tuning.

Comment: Also from the docs, `By default optim performs minimization, but it will maximize if control$fnscale is negative.` (though you can also just negate the result). But as Gabor pointed out above, this goes to infinity at 0, 0, so optimization is going to go weird.